# How to open an url in new tab using a button in vb.net which using command name not by the click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying the open url using a button . But in this case i'm not using button click event, I am using the commandname to right code behind for the url. I can goto the url but it is happening in the same tab but i want it to open in a new tab. here is the button i'm using

```html
  <asp:Button ID="btneditinformation" runat="server" CommandName="editinformation" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Edit information in QuickBase" Text="Edit Information" Height="30px" Width="100px"
                                                 OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"></asp:Button>
```

and this is the code behind i am trying to use

```
 ElseIf e.CommandName = "editinformation" Then

        Response.Redirect(url)
    End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The url changes dynamically. So i can't use the javascript

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the script manager to help you execute javascript after the server returns a response:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "NewWindow", "window.open('" + url + "');", true);
```

Comment: Where do i need to keep the code ?  do i need to still  use response ?

Comment: Replace the Response.Redirect statement with this.

Comment: This is not in the page load it is in a method which is a part of telerik radscheduler

Answer (score 0):

There are two approach:

1. you can do the same by jquery

   ```
     $("#btneditinformation").click(function () {
       window.open("URL","_blank")
     })
   ```
2. You can use anchor tag with giving proper css class for button.

   `<a class="btn btn-success" target="_blank" href="#">Link</a>`

Comment: It's not working it is stil opening up in the same tab